# Означать изначально

Tags: стилистика

Писала предыдущий вопрос о неряшливости и хотела употребить конструкцию "означал изначально".
"Означал" и "изначально" - слова разные по смыслу, и корни у них разные, но звучат очень похоже.
Скажите, пожалуйста, с точки зрения стилистики такое словосочетание допустимо или лучше его избегать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы внимание читателя не переключалось на восприятие созвучий и поиск подвоха (не шутит ли автор?), можно сказать проще: "первоначально это значило" или "изначальный смысл был таким-то". В первом варианте повторяющееся "нач" незаметно, поскольку в одном слове оно под ударением, в другом -нет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

По моему мнению, таких словосочетаний лучше избегать, не смотря на то, что **означал** - это **знак**, а **изначально** - **начало**, то есть семантика различна, на первый взгляд(знак - это так же начало своего рода). Именно концентрация большого количества одинаковых звуков - **знач**, повторяющихся в словах, стоящих рядом, делает неблагозвучной данную конструкцию. "Исконно означал", изначально представлял, какой смысл имел изначально...